Is it correct to say "don't eat walking around" or "don't walk around eating"?
I want my children to stay in one place and eat rather than walking around while eating.
So, if we want to emphasize a word, we put it before other words right?
I don't know which action I should emphasize? "eat" or "walk around"?
Is it correct to say "don't eat walking around" or "don't walk around eating"?

Another option is to set aside what behavior you don’t want and speak instead of the behavior you do want. Something like Please sit [or stand] still when you are eating.

Or "Don't eat while walking around". or "Don't be eating while walking around."

Only you know which action you want to endorse, if the children are not to do both simultaneously, "Don't [do secondary activity] [while you are] [doing primary activity]"

This isn't really about grammar; both versions are 'correct'. If you are talking about a family meal, it makes sense to say "Don't walk around [while you are] eating" (that is, during the meal).

The second form sounds more natural to me, though I have no good reason to prefer it. It suggests to me that both eating and walking around can be done, but they should not be combined. The way it is said might indicate which of the two activities should be stopped now.

Clarity
This is clearer:

Don't walk around while you are eating.

This is even clearer:

Sit down and stay in one place while you are eating.

It's usually clearer to ask for what you want than to ask someone to not do what you don't want. (This principle isn't specific to English, of course.)

Emphasis
But I understand your question to be about emphasis and grammar, not about how to ask your children to stay put while eating. I don't think that any simple rule determines which concept gets the most emphasis in phrases of the form "don't verb verbing". But it might help to understand some factors that simultaneously influence emphasis:

Coming first gives a word emphasis. For example, "Don't smoke while you are inside the museum."

Coming last gives a word emphasis. For example, "Don't be in the museum smoking."

The head verb gets emphasis. For example, "Don't walk around eating", "Don't eat walking around."


"Don't eat walking around" puts a little more emphasis on eating: you are making a statement about eating, in general, not so much about walking around. A stronger version of the same emphasis: "When you are eating, don't walk around." A listener might understand that you're trying to promote good digestion or at least prevent spills. A listener imagines that someone is already eating, and now the option of walking around is up for consideration.
"Don't walk around eating" puts a little more emphasis on walking around: you're making a statement about walking around in general, not so much about eating. A stronger version of the same emphasis: "When you are walking around, don't eat." A listener might understand that you're trying to prevent him or her from walking into something or tripping over something, or to just carry food to a table before starting to eat. A listener imagines that someone is already walking, and eating comes up for consideration.
But context and intonation could easily shift these emphases the other way around.

Without while connecting your two clauses, your sentences sound like the following, where the two actions  are integral to each other, not simply  being done at the same time.

The potential buyer walked around pointing out all the places where the house was in need of repair.
He went around bad-mouthing the mayor.

Your sentences would be more idiomatic with while since your two actions (walking, eating) are not integrally related; rather they are unrelated actions being done at the same time.
